# Use std::array of type T to construct std::array of type constructable from T

Tags: c++, arrays, stl

Please consider these types:

```
struct Part
{
    float data;
};

struct Wrap
{
    Wrap( const Part& p )
        :data( p.data )
    {}
    float data;
};
```

Now I would like to use an `std::array<Part, N>` to initialize an `std::array<Wrap, N>`.

```
int main()
{
    std::array<Part, 3> parts{ Part{ 1.0f }, Part{ 2.0f }, Part{ 3.0f } };
    std::array<Wrap, 3> wrappers( parts );
    return 0;
}
```

( This throws the error `"conversion from 'std::array<Part, 3>' to non-scalar type 'std::array<Wrap, 3>' requested"` )

How can I use an `std::array` of type `T` to initialize an `std::array` of a type which is constructable from `T`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a helper function to automate conversion:

```
// Convert each element based on a sequence of indices:
template<typename ToType, typename FromType, std::size_t... Indices>
std::array<ToType, sizeof...(Indices)>
convert_impl(const std::array<FromType, sizeof...(Indices)>& input, std::index_sequence<Indices...>)
{
    return {ToType(std::get<Indices>(input))...};
}

// Wraps convert_impl to hide the use of index_sequence from users:
template<typename ToType, typename FromType, std::size_t N>
std::array<ToType, N> convert(const std::array<FromType, N>& input)
{
    return convert_impl<ToType>(input, std::make_index_sequence<N>{});
}

int main()
{
    std::array<Part, 3> parts {Part{1.0f}, Part{2.0f}, Part{3.0f}};
    std::array<Wrap, 3> wraps = convert<Wrap>(parts);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Possible simple options are:

O. Use `vector` instead (arrays are still evil 0_o).

```
    std::vector<Part> ps{Part{1.0}, Part{2.0}, Part{3.0}};
    std::vector<Wrap> ws(ps.cbegin(), ps.cend());
```

I. Make it explicit.

```
    std::array<Part, 3> parts{ Part{ 1.0f }, Part{ 2.0f }, Part{ 3.0f } };
    std::array<Wrap, 3> wrappers = {parts[0], parts[1], parts[2]};
```

II. Split construction and initialization.

```
struct Unwrap {
    Unwrap() {}
    Unwrap(Part const &p): data(p.data) {}
    float data;
};

int main() {
    std::array<Part, 3> parts{ Part{ 1.0f }, Part{ 2.0f }, Part{ 3.0f } };
    std::array<Unwrap, 3> unwrappers;
    std::copy(parts.cbegin(), parts.cend(), unwrappers.begin());
}
```

BTW, does your code with parentheses in `Part` initialization even compile? I could only make it to by changing them to braces.

Comment: Oh yes my fault, I should have either added a constructor for `Part` or used braces.